# I can not display bookmarks for the user (django)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm trying to make the function of adding and displaying bookmarks (favorites) of the user. I do the guide.

What is at the moment:

1. User bookmarks are successfully added successfully to the database
2. **I can not display the bookmarks that the user added**

Below I attach the code that adds a bookmark for the user.

**models.py**

Article Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):

title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True,)
slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True,)
content = RichTextUploadingField()


def get_bookmark_count(self):
    return self.bookmarkarticle_set.all().count() #

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Abstract model:

```
class BookmarkBase(models.Model):
class Meta:
    abstract = True

user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name="user")

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

Inherited Model:

```
class BookmarkArticle(BookmarkBase):
class Meta:
    db_table = "bookmark_article"

obj = models.ForeignKey(Post, verbose_name="article")
```

**views.py**

```
class BookmarkView(View):

model = None

def post(self, request, pk):

    user = auth.get_user(request)
    bookmark, created = self.model.objects.get_or_create(user=user, obj_id=pk)

    if not created:
        bookmark.delete()

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({
            "result": created,
            "count": self.model.objects.filter(obj_id=pk).count()
        }),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

I'm trying to display bookmarks in the template that the user added:

```
{% for bookmark in user.bookmarkarticle_set.all %}
{{ bookmark.post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

Nothing is output.

**What needs to be done to display the bookmarks that the user has added?**

I would be grateful for any help.

[Bookmarked guide source](https://evileg.com/en/post/244/)

Comment: I don't really understand your code... In your view, you declare model as `None` and then try `self.model.objects.get_or_create(user=user, obj_id=pk)`... Are you sure it doesn't throw any errors? Because by the looks of view.py, it looks like you are running a function on `None`.

Comment: Yes, bookmarks are added and deleted successfully. model = none - this variable will be set bookmarks model, which must be processed

Comment: The only problem is that I do not know how to display them in a template

Comment: I have a suspicion that something needs to be done in views.py

Comment: In your templates, can you try `request.user.bookmarkarticle.all`

Comment: tried adding views.py   `def profile(request):
    context = {'bookmarks': request.user.bookmarkarticle.all }
    return render(request,'users/profile/profile.html', context)` -  Got an error:  `'User' object has no attribute 'bookmarkarticle'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post is referenced through the `BookmarkArticle` model using the name: `obj`, so try to use `bookmark.obj.title` in your template or change the field name from `obj` to `post`

Comment: Thank you very much, I suffered for several days. Everything is working !